# how to add 30 minutes in last value of return query using oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

My query is

```
Select class_time from tableA
```

which produces:

```
0200AM
0230AM
0300AM
0330AM
0400AM
```

i want above result as

```
0200AM
0230AM
0300AM
0330AM
0400AM
0430AM
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are storing the times in a `DATE` data type (which always has year, month, day, hour, minute and second components) then add an `INTERVAL` literal to the maximum value from the table:

```sql
SELECT class_time from tableA
UNION ALL
SELECT MAX( class_time ) + INTERVAL '30' MINUTE FROM tableA
```

or add a fraction of a day:

```sql
SELECT class_time from tableA
UNION ALL
SELECT MAX( class_time ) + 30 / ( 24 /* hours */ * 60 /* minutes */ )  FROM tableA
```

**Output**:

> ```
> | CLASS_TIME          |
> | :------------------ |
> | 2019-12-16 02:00:00 |
> | 2019-12-16 02:30:00 |
> | 2019-12-16 03:00:00 |
> | 2019-12-16 03:30:00 |
> | 2019-12-16 04:00:00 |
> | 2019-12-16 04:30:00 |
> ```

---

If your times are stored as strings then convert them to a date, add 30 minutes and then convert back to a string:

```sql
SELECT class_time from tableB
UNION ALL
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         MAX( TO_DATE( class_time, 'HH12:MI AM' ) )
         + INTERVAL '30' MINUTE,
         'HH12:MI AM'
       )
FROM   tableB
```

**Output**:

> ```
> | CLASS_TIME |
> | :--------- |
> | 02:00 AM   |
> | 02:30 AM   |
> | 03:00 AM   |
> | 03:30 AM   |
> | 04:00 AM   |
> | 04:30 AM   |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=61a3af39bacb8897a7e06d60c79e8465)*

Answer (score 2):

You can use a CTE and `union all`:

```
with cte as (
      <your query here>
     )
select time
from cte
union all
select max(time) + interval '30' minute
from cte;
```